# ValidateAntiForgeryToken tokens work but don't match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I thought this was fairly simple stuff. `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is a filter attribute that we can apply to our post methods on an MVC controller.

It will check that the value of hidden form field `__RequestVerificationToken`, injected via call to the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` helper matches an Http-Cookie value. So weirdly it seems to work but I now upon review don't understand how since the values don't match:

[image]

Using Google Dev tools I get the following Headers on post back to a log-in form. I had expected the two values underlined in red to match, but they don't and yet everything still "works". So, how does `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` work since the values that i thought were being compared on the server - don't actually match?

Comment: The values don't need to match, they just need to validate. Anti-forgery tokens wouldn't work out that great if they generated the same values repeatedly.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought the tokens were generated per request and the comparision is between the value in the html which can be repliciated in a XSRF attack and a matching value in the user's browser which would not be present and therefore fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in the html form field and that exposed by looking at the cookie in the response header are different because they are in fact serialized payloads containing different numbers of properties.

So while somewhere in the html form field __RequestVerificationToken there exists a value for request token, there also exists values for the salt of the encryption used.

Whereas the Http-Cookie in the response header may contain that information plus other encrypted data like user identity data and roles all bundled together and then serialized.

This is why they look different on the client using sniffing tools / view page source  etc. They are different sized bundles of data that have been serialized. ***So what we see is not the token but rather a serialized object containing the token.***

So while each request parameter (__RequestVerificationToken form field and __RequestVerificationToken cookie) contains an exact match for the other, the visible strings we see for each of these parameters, as per the image I uploaded will be different because those strings are NOT the actual tokens but rather the serialized output of the objects containing the tokens.

It's not until the whole request is posted back to the server and the server deserializes these strings we see in the image above into objects that we get some raw properties that can be compared for a match.